# Does the IOB tagging method for Named Entity Recognition (NER) has any advantage in terms of model accuracy or computational time?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

Can we do NER without the IOB tags and with only the entities as labels? I am specifically working on token classification for visual documents like receipts. For example, [This HuggingFace tutorial](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/LayoutLMv2/CORD/Fine_tuning_LayoutLMv2ForTokenClassification_on_CORD.ipynb) for LayoutLM on the CORD dataset for receipt information extraction does not use the IOB scheme.

I have trained the LayoutLMv2 model without IOB tagging and it trains well. But will doing it with IOB tags make any difference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking just this - is using the IOB method in NER necessary? If instead I create labels without these Begin/Inside/Outside tags, will my model performance be inferior?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that your text is "... dark blue light green ...", where "dark blue" and "light green" are two different colours. If you want to make sure your model understands this difference, you should use IOB to check that the result is I-Color I-Color B-Color I-Color. If you just care that the model classifies these words as colours, no IOB tagging is needed.

From this it can be quite clear that the chosen tagging influences the performance metrics. Finding the correct tag-class couple is more complicated than just finding the correct class. In terms of computational time, I believe it has a minor impact due to the increase in total number of classes when including also IOB tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I assume that you mean the tags would be B-color I-color B-color I-color. Apart from that, how is it different from using 'color color color color'? Does it mean that the model learns that the words 'dark' and 'light' would always appear in the beginning of colours and that it is different from the phrase 'blue dark' (so learns some order in one sense).

Comment: If that is the case, then it surely helps in this scenario but may be not in case of 'firstname lastname' type entities where the order of words do not matter?

Comment: Depending on the IOB version used, the first token is classified as I-Color or B-Color, but this is not key to us now. The fact is that if you only classify the tokens with 'color color color color', your model learns that all the tokens are just expressing a colour. However, with the tagging you get something more: the model learns that 'dark blue' is a specific chunk of text with some meaning, and 'light green' is another chunk which is still expressing a colour but different from the previous one. They are 2 different entities.

Comment: It really boils down to the task. If you have multiple entities of the same concept, so a sequence of such entities, you will probably need IOB to distinguish them. If you have 2 names for example, 'Leonardo Perelli ... Sagar Uprety...' it might not be enough to tag them as names, but it might be necessary to distinguish my name (chunk of tokens 'Leonardo' and 'Perelli') from the other 2 tokens of your name. Hope it helps, I am not an expert but this should be the reason behind IOB